# Extract lower limit of pvalue less than 2.2*10^-16

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am using linear mixed model to get p values that are used to plot graph . The R package that I am using for the model is multcomp and the function that is used from multcomp package is glht. From the output I get some pvalues that are less than 2. 210^-16 but in the output it is shown as value of 0. I need to extract the exact p values for pvalues less than 2.210^-16 instead of 0's.

I extraced p values by taking summary(model)$test$pvalues in R

I would highly appreciate if anybody can guide me how to exact pvalues that are less than 2.2*10^-16 so that I can make a QTL plot with right hieght of the peaks of multiple hypothesis adjusted -logQ values against human genome.

Comment: You won't get smaller values than that because they can't be handled reliably. See `double.eps` in `?.Machine`.

Comment: @Gregor In genetics, it matters, see some of these Manhattan plots, y axis is -`log10(pvalue)`: for example [this plot](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2015/151007/ncomms9469/fig_tab/ncomms9469_F2.html)

Comment: **if** you could get the p-values back on the log scale you could do this.  Getting p-values back on the natural log scale from `glht` is no too hard; if you have the Z-statistic you just need `pnorm(abs(z),lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)+log(2)` (the `log(2)` is to get two-tailed p-values). However, doing the multiple comparisons correction on log-p rather than p values might be tricky depending on how you do it. Naive Bonferroni would be easy, other methods (especially those depending on multivariate t distributions) could be tricky.

Comment: I think Benjamin-Hochberg (BH/FDR) wouldn't be too hard to implement on the log scale either, **if** you were willing to assume that all of the tests were independent.  Correlated tests will make life a lot harder.

Comment: Hi Dr. Ben Bolker, I believe I would be able to get either z or t-statistics from the model and I will try your suggestion. I highly appreciated your input. If I have further question I will post them in future. Thanks.

Comment: Use `@` before username to ping the user, like this: @BenBolker . If you find a solution, please post as an answer below to help future users having the same question.

Comment: Hi, for my question above

Comment: I tried @Ben Bolker Suggestion of using z statistics to get lower limit p values , however values are then not corrected for multiple hypothesis(used linear mixed model and glht function from multcomp R package) .  So is it ok to use those values to plot against human genome or we have to adjust the values between samples in each row prior to do any further analysis.  I highly appreciate your input